# Getting compile error on passing my tasks to for join pool

Tags: java, java-threads

I have the following code trying to create my own RecursiveAction and use fork join framework in java to run them:

```
class MyTask extends RecursiveAction {
  int[] a;
  int start;
  int end;

  public MyTask(int[] a, int start, int end) {
    this.a = a;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  @Override
  protected void compute() {
    if(end - start <= 3) {
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)   a[i]++;
    }else {
        int middle = (end + start) / 2;
        List<MyTask> myTasks = Arrays.asList(
                new MyTask(a, start, middle),
                new MyTask(a, middle, end)
        );
        ForkJoinPool.commonPool().invokeAll(myTasks);
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to call invokeAll method on my thread pool and pass the list of my tasks I get the following compilation error:

> java: no suitable method found for invokeAll(java.util.List)
> method java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll(java.util.Collection<? extends java.util.concurrent.Callable>) is not applicable

I appreciate if you can tell me what I am missing here.

P.S. I think the problem was that I had to call the invokeAll method on my task instead of thread pool but still what I don't get is why it fails if I call thread pool invokeAll method?!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. I have to call the invokeAll method on my RecursiveAction rather than thread pool.